# Sending External ID Fields in change data capture(CDC) payload

Tags: platform-event, change-data-capture

We have an external system(legacy) from where we will data convert and move the data to salesforce.

Lets say the object name is 'Relationship'. every time later when data changes in salesforce for the data converted records, we have to send it to the external system through mulesoft to keep them in sync.

We are considering using CDC using mulesoft. CDC will publish the modified record's Id and modified fields to mulesoft for the objects we select . In our case the external systems schema for the objects cannot be modified to include new fields so we need to send their unique ID identifier(External ID Field in salesforce) in the payload to mule.

**Question:**
Is there anyway to include external ID fields in payload to mulesoft when CDC publishes an event for any object record?

I read the documentation and i cant find any information related to this

Comment: Are you saying you want to include an external id field every time a record has been changed, even if the external id field was not updated? Or you are looking for in general that if external id field is included in the payload every time there's a change on that field?

Comment: @JayantDas - i want the external id to be included if its not updated. Also is there a way to include external id fields everytime?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no control provided to specify a particular field to be included. The only fields included in the response are those which have been updated.

Comment: @JayantDas- thank you, i will use platform events instead then. set the fields i want and publish it when middleware can subscribe to. I did not want to use code thats why wanted to try out CDC. i could also use CDC to send id to mulesoft and then do a callback from mule to pull the required data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Adam mentioned there's an "Change Data Capture Enrichment" closed pilot that started in Winter '20 and is continuing in Spring '20:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_change_data_capture_enrichment.htm

This pilot covers this exact use case of adding fields like external IDs to CDC events. These "always included" fields appear in the event even if their value doesn't change.

Check out this [Trailblazer Community group](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTvs) for more info.

Comment: Thank you @POZ, I will join the group and hopefully it becomes GA

Answer (score 0):

There is a pilot program in Salesforce right now for enriching CDC events that I believe is slated for general release later this year. We are using it and are able to include an external ID with each cdc message.